# How to use JSR 380 bean validation annotations in a Java SE project

Tags: java, bean-validation

Just tried to run my simple programme with the main method using JSR 380 annotation, but it is not working for me.

here is the code...

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Request request = new Request(5);
    }
}

class Request{

    public Request(int greaterThan10) {
        super();
        this.greaterThan10 = greaterThan10;
    }

    @Min(value = 10,message= "value should be greater than 10")
    private int greaterThan10;

    public int getOne2Ten() {
        return greaterThan10;
    }

    public void setOne2Ten(int greaterThan10) {
        this.greaterThan10 = greaterThan10;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what "but it is not working for me" exactly means?

Comment: You need to actually call the `validate()` method on Validator (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Validator.html) to trigger the validation. As for usage in Java SE, not sure but you'll find out this way.

Comment: @UwePlonus I am not able to see any output on the console. as I am expecting the message "value should be greater than 10"

Comment: not sure why you guys downcast to my question without giving me clear answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code isn't running in a managed environment such as a Java EE or Spring container, you must manually invoke the `Validator` API. I.e. you'd have something like this in your `main()` method:

```
Request request = new Request(5);
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Request>> violations = validator.validate(request);
```